# Covert String into Hexbytes

Tags: python, django, hex, web3py

I have this signature `b'V\xae\xc1\x0bU:\xcaV0\xcbBO@\xe6\xf7\x9c\xb3\xe4R\xa0\xb4\x10\xcf\x1e\x9b\xc3\x03\t\x84\xf9\x92!\xd2p\x12\x16*\x8biJ\xfeNq\x11\xfa5\x05\n\x19*9\xdak\x989j\xd8:\x7f\xdd\x03\xa2\xd7\x1c'`

but it is in string format. I am using

```
w3.eth.account.recover_message(encode_defunct(
        text=account_address.challenge), signature=signature)
```

to get address back, but as it only accepts <class 'hexbytes.main.HexBytes'> format. So can please anyone help me convert this value into Hexbytes but as you can see value of string should not change.

I am using django here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = b"V\xae\xc1\x0bU:\xcaV0\xcbBO@\xe6\xf7\x9c\xb3\xe4R\xa0\xb4\x10\xcf\x1e\x9b\xc3\x03\t\x84\xf9\x92!\xd2p\x12\x16*\x8biJ\xfeNq\x11\xfa5\x05\n\x19*9\xdak\x989j\xd8:\x7f\xdd\x03\xa2\xd7\x1c"
def hex_bytes(b):
    return ":".join("{:02x}".format(c) for c in b)

print(hex_bytes(s))
```